# do_action Nested List

Tags: plugins, actions

I have a plugin with two custom post types - Projects and Tasks. In the plugin, you can assign tasks to projects. So, for example you might have a "Website Design" project with Tasks "Purchase Domain Name", "Customize Theme", "Add Content", etc.

What I'm trying to do is create a list of projects, and create a nested list of tasks below each project like this.

- Project 1

  - Task 1
  - Task 2
- Project 2

  - Task 3
  - Task 4

In HTML, I know that this works:

```
<ul>
    <li>Project 1
        <ul>
            <li>Task 1</li>
            <li>Task 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Project 2
        <ul>
            <li>Task 3</li>
            <li>Task 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My plugin generates the list for Projects and Tasks in two separate functions. I include the tasks in the Project list by using `do_action( 'my-task-action', $project_id )`

**Display projects**

```
$project_option .= '<ul class="project-list">';
    foreach( $projects as $project ) {
    $project_id = $project->ID;
    $project_option .= '
        <li class="project" id="project-' . $project_id . '">
            <span class="project-title">' . get_the_title( $project_id ) . ' </span>
            <span class="project-status-title">' . __( 'Project Status: ', 'client-area' ) . '</span>
            <span class="project-status">' .  get_post_meta( $project_id, 'project-status', true ) . '</span>' .
            do_action( 'my-task-action', $project_id ) . '
        </li>';
    }
$project_option .= '</ul>';
echo $project_option;
```

**Display Tasks**

The function to display the tasks gets the project ID passed to it through `do_action( 'my-task-action', $project_id )`, and can display each task assigned to each project.

```
$task_option .= '<ul class="task-list">';
    foreach( $tasks as $task ) {
        $task_id = $task->ID;
        $task_option .= '
        <li class="task project-' . $project_id . '" id="task-' . $task_id . '">
            <span class="task-title">' . get_the_title( $task_id ) . ' </span>
            <span class="task-status-title">' . __( 'Task Status: ', 'client-area' ) . '</span>
            <span class="task-status">' .  get_post_meta( $task_id, 'task-status', true ) . '</span>
        </li>';
    }
    $task_option .= '</ul>';
}
echo $task_option;
```

**The Problem**

Instead of a nested list like I displayed above, I get the Tasks in one list and Projects in a separate list.

- Task 1
- Task 2
- Task 3
- Task 4
- Project 1
- Project 2

Or...

```
<ul class="task-list">
    <li class="task project-1023" id="task-929">
        <span class="task-title">Task 1 </span>
        <span class="task-status-title">Task Status: </span>
        <span class="task-status">on-hold</span>
    </li>
    <li class="task project-1023" id="task-927">
        <span class="task-title">Task 2 </span>
        <span class="task-status-title">Task Status: </span>
        <span class="task-status">not-started</span>
    </li>
    <li class="task project-930" id="task-931">
        <span class="task-title">Task 3 </span>
        <span class="task-status-title">Task Status: </span>
        <span class="task-status">on-hold</span>
    </li>
    <li class="task project-930" id="task-932">
        <span class="task-title">Task 4 </span>
        <span class="task-status-title">Task Status: </span>
        <span class="task-status">not-started</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="project-list">
    <li class="project" id="project-1023">
        <span class="project-title">Project 1 </span>
        <span class="project-status-title">Project Status: </span>
        <span class="project-status">in-progress</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project" id="project-930">
        <span class="project-title">Project 2 </span>
        <span class="project-status-title">Project Status: </span>
        <span class="project-status">complete</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Based on where the do_action is in the list, I would think that the task list would simply be output inside the project's `<li></li>`, and cause a nested list to be used.

Any idea why this isn't working the way I'm expecting it to?

Comment: It is because your `do_action` `echo`'s the output. Instead of using do_action, you should create a function like `get_tasks_for_project($project_id)` and this function should return a string, like `return $task_option`

Comment: Yes, if I do it that way, it works correctly. However I'd like to keep the `do_action` so users can hook into that area if they want to modify the output of tasks.

Comment: Then you should use `apply_filters('my-task-action', $project_id )` and then use `add_filter('my-task-action', 'my_callback')` with `function my_callback($value){ return $value; }`

Comment: That's what I was missing...I think just a case of staring at it too long. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If that worked for you then please write it up as an answer to keep the site format useful for others.  After 2 days you can mark your own answer as accepted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a value in your hook, use `apply_filters` instead of `do_action`, like:

```
$project_option .= '<ul class="project-list">';
    foreach( $projects as $project ) {
    $project_id = $project->ID;
    $project_option .= '
        <li class="project" id="project-' . $project_id . '">
            <span class="project-title">' . get_the_title( $project_id ) . ' </span>
            <span class="project-status-title">' . __( 'Project Status: ', 'client-area' ) . '</span>
            <span class="project-status">' .  get_post_meta( $project_id, 'project-status', true ) . '</span>' .
            apply_filters( 'my-task-action', $project_id ) . '
        </li>';
    }
$project_option .= '</ul>';
echo $project_option;
```

and then have an `add_filter` like

```
add_filter('my-task-action', 'wpse241018_getTaskActions');

function wpse241018_getTaskActions($project_id){ 
    $task_option .= '<ul class="task-list">';
    foreach( $tasks as $task ) {
        $task_id = $task->ID;
        $task_option .= '
        <li class="task project-' . $project_id . '" id="task-' . $task_id . '">
            <span class="task-title">' . get_the_title( $task_id ) . ' </span>
            <span class="task-status-title">' . __( 'Task Status: ', 'client-area' ) . '</span>
            <span class="task-status">' .  get_post_meta( $task_id, 'task-status', true ) . '</span>
        </li>';
     }
    $task_option .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $task_option; 
}
```